# Limiting the scrolling of left and rights with jquery to stop overscroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a snippet of code that I've gotten from: [How can i add animate effect for scrolling right and left on button click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828656/how-can-i-add-animate-effect-for-scrolling-right-and-left-on-button-click) | http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/

The only problem that I have with it is that it can scroll too far to the left or too far to the right. I'm looking for a way to stop it from going too far.

#### I changed it so that it's as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("a.abc").click(function() {
        $("#container").each(function(){
            $(this).animate({"margin-left":"-=204px"},200)  
                });
    });

    $("a.def").click(function() {
                $("#container").each(function(){
                    $(this).animate({"margin-left":"+=204px"},200)
                });
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas, suggestions or advice would be very much welcome.

#### css code

```
body {
    line-height: 1.6em;
    background-color: #0E4216;
    width: 3200px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#gs {
    font-family: "Times New Roman",Serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

#### html code

```
<div id="main">
    <table id="gs" summary="">
        <tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data123</th>
                    <th scope="col">title</th>
                    <th scope="col">title data</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text (data text)</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                    <th scope="col">data text</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

#### My attempt at getting method supplied by dmitry

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {

    var animationFlag = true;
    var windowW = $(window).width();
    var itemW = $('#scroller th:first').width();
    var visibleItems = parseInt(windowW / itemW, 10);
    var maxRight = ($('#scroller th').length - visibleItems) * (-204);
    $('#main').css('width', visibleItems * itemW + 'px');

    $("a.abc").click(function() {
        $("#gs").each(function(){
            if (parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'), 10) > maxRight && animationFlag) {
                animationFlag = false;
                $(this).animate({"margin-left":"-=204px"},800, function() {
                    animationFlag = true;
                });
            }
        });

    });
    $("a.def").click(function() {
        $("#gs").each(function(){
            if (parseInt($(this).css('margin-left'), 10) < 0 && animationFlag) {        
                animationFlag = false;
                $(this).animate({"margin-left":"+=204px"},800, function(){
                    animationFlag = true;
                });
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

#### Edited HTML Snippet

```
<div id="main">
    <table id="gs" id="scroller">
```

Can any one provide any constructive comments or help with this?

Comment: well you can control it with your margin left..are u talking about stopping the scroll after certaing threshhold?

Comment: @Onaseriousnote Yes, I have added some code in my original post to show my page layout. Any ideas how to create a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 4):

if you are looking for a way to stop it you can use something like this modifications:
[http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/127/]

animation with flag option: [http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/128/][1]

Comment: Thanks for replying I have tried your code, it worked to an extent but, it seems to have a little bug. If I change the animation time from 800 to 1500 it allows me to overscroll, If I set it to 100 it very very rarely allows me to overscroll.

Comment: if you want to stop this effect so when the animation starts you have to set some flag = false and when the animation stops set this flag = true. So when you start you animation you have to check this flag if it's true

Comment: Hmm I can't seem to get this to work with my example html and css. Is there any chance of you helping me integrate this?

Comment: Added my attempt into the question

Comment: so, you want to do it with a table width a fixes TD width?

Comment: I added more data and the page died again, checkout: http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/145/ for the problem in question. I added some `<tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>` code. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because you have hardcoded width values in your divs.

Comment: I have added the css and some html, the page in question is html table and it is rather large in width. Do you have any idea how I should get around this?

Answer (score 0):

I thik that what you are looking for: [http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/138/]

Comment: Looks good, I'm unable though to get it working with my css :/

Comment: @DnutryDvomikov I've made a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/143/ and I've been trying to incorperate it into that without any color changes or major changes... any ideas?

Comment: I posted on your other post: I added more data and the page died again, checkout: jsfiddle.net/MMyGE/145 for the problem in question. I added some `<tr><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</‌​td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td><td>data</td></tr>` code. Any thoughts